# Can we use scaleapp.js and angular together

Tags: angularjs

We have used scaleapp.js with backbone but not sure if we can use scaleapp with angular also. Is this combination possible or we cannot marry them.
Can anyone share their viewpoints on this.

Comment: www.scaleapp.org website doesn't load at the moment so its hard to know what it is. Could you provide some more information about it?

Comment: You can use this http://scaleapp.org/

Comment: scaleApp is a tiny JavaScript framework for scalable and maintainable One-Page-Applications / Single-Page-Applications. The framework allows you to easily create complex web applications.We can dynamically start and stop/destroy modules that acts as small parts of your whole application.